# Node create image by mixing 2 images

Tags: node.js, image-processing

I've got app based on google maps. Each user is one pin on it.

I want to create pin image basing on user profile photo.

What I need to do is

- Resize given image to given size (50x50px)
- Make this image circle
- Below this image, put base pin image (png) that has place on it for circle photo
- Save final image as pin photo

Final image should be png with transparency enabled.

Is there any node library that can do such things?

Answer (score 0):

Imagemagick supports [image composition](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/compose/), and node has [Imagemagick bindings](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=imagemagick).

Even though, I guess you can achieve your goal via CSS only:

- resize -> browser will do;
- make it circle -> `border-radius: 50%`;
- base pin image background -> `background-image`.

Comment: I don't want browser to resize files like 1000x1000px becouse of performance and net traffic.

Comment: [Well, then use imagemagick just to create thumbnails](https://www.google.de/webhp?q=node%20imagemagick%20thumbnail#safe=off&q=node+imagemagick+thumbnail) : ))